# Non equivalent isometric embeddings of the plane

Tags: euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I would like to see an explicit example of two smooth isometric embeddings (in the Riemannian sense) $i_1,i_2:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that there is no isometry $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ suct that $i_2=\varphi\circ i_1$.

(I take here $\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^3$ to be endowed with the standard Euclidean metrics).

Also, does there exist a pair of embeddings $i_1,i_2$ such that their *images* are not equivalent, i.e there is no isometry $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ suct that $\text{Image}(i_2)=\varphi (\text{Image}(i_1))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a unit speed curve $\alpha \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ whose image lies in the $xy$ plane and consider the map $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by

$$ \varphi(s,t) = \alpha(s) + te_3 $$

where $e_3 = (0,0,1)$. The image of $\varphi$ is a cylinder over $\alpha$ with axis $e_3$. The differential of $\varphi$ is $(\alpha'(s), e_3)$ and since $\alpha'(s),e_3$ are orthogonal to each other and of unit length, this is an isometric immersion. If $\alpha$ is an embedding, you'll get an embedding. By choosing $\alpha$ appropriately, it is clear you can get an embedding whose image is not congruent to a plane (which itself can be considered as a cylinder over a line with axis that lies in the plane and s perpendicular to that line).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, how about taking one image to be $\{x,y,0\}$ and the other $\{x,y,\sin x\}$?

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but is $(x,y) \to (x,y,\sin x)$ an *isometric* embedding?

Comment: @AsafShachar No, but $(x,y) \mapsto (f(x),y,\sin(f(x)))$ is isometric for some appropriate strictly increasing function $f$, which I didn't feel like working out explicitly :)